# Help to recognize font

Tags: fonts

Anyone know which font is used in the text "BLOG BUSINESS" in this page - http://rockablepress.com/books/blog-business/

Comment: from CSS font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-

Comment: note that the text in that font appears in the image http://rockable.s3.amazonaws.com/BlogBusiness/sprite.png which is used on that page

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try a resource such as [WhatTheFont](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/).

Answer (score 1):

This font is **Futura Bold.** It is possibly **Futura Bold Oblique**, or they might have skewed the font to get the appropriate angle for the design aesthetic.

*Did you know?* Futura is a geometric sans-serif font that was created in 1927, and soon became a visual trademark of the Bauhaus design style.